# TYPO3 Fluid single engine

Tags: php, typo3, fluid

Is it possible to get FLUID as a Standalone template engine like Twig?
I do not want to use TYPO3 (Neos) neither do I want to use Flow. Since it is way to overkill for a small project.
Has everyone ever tried using Fluid as a Standalone template Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new answer to this question is: yes.

Here is standalone fluid: https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a stable and standalone version of the FLUID template engine, but have seen some projects on GitHub that at least contain the basic functionality and some of the ViewHelpers included in FLUID (see links below).

- https://github.com/janvennemann/typo3-fluid-standalone
- https://github.com/NamelessCoder/fluid